# React native + typescript can't see ts in chrome debugger

Tags: typescript, react-native, chrome-debugging

I recently started a react native project with typescript, redux, react navigation and redux saga.

Everything worked fine.

I noticed, when I want to debug in chrome debugger I can not see the ts files, these I see only the js and when I put debugger in the code it stops only in js file.

At first I thought the problem in my project, so I opened a new project with the command:

`react-native init MyAwesomeProject --template typescript`

And still I can not seem to see ts.
In addition I downloaded the project https://github.com/mmazzarolo/just-tap and also there I can not see ts files.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "FlatMates",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.8",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "typesafe-actions": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.7.17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.18",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.5",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["esnext"], /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": false,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

[Chrome debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po7dN.png)

[Sometimes I see some of the ts files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyfSW.png)

(The App.js is ts too)

Comment: Well, you will not see the typescript files because your code is being transpiled to javascript before run. Take a look to [this article](https://hackernoon.com/debugging-javascript-typescript-node-apps-with-chrome-devtools-vs-code-and-webstorm-97b882aee0ad), perhaps it can help you.

Comment: I know, but some strange things:
1. As you can see in the picture I can see some of the files as ts (each time it's other files).
2. By default "sourceMap": true so I need to see the .ts files.
3. In an older version of the react-native and ts I have been able to see the files (I have no access to this project anymore).